# I want to write better jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I'm relatively new to jQuery and I while I'm trying to learn, I have this worry that I'm doing things... well not wrong... but not necessarily the right way.

I have the script below which works fine and does what I need it to do. But looking at it, I'm not satisfied, is it really the best way of achieving my goal or am I being too picky?

Brief description of what I'm building: A search form containing dynamically generated field. Each field has 2 classes to specify whether or not it should appear in the quick and/or advanced search form. Two links to toggle between the two views.

```
function searchModes() {
    $('p.quicksearch-true.advancedsearch-true').show();
    $('p.quicksearch-true.advancedsearch-false').show();
    $('p.quicksearch-false.advancedsearch-true').hide();
    $('p.quicksearch-false.advancedsearch-false').hide();
    $('#advanced').show();
    $('#quick').hide();

    $('#advanced').click(function () {
        $('p.quicksearch-true.advancedsearch-true').show();
        $('p.quicksearch-true.advancedsearch-false').hide();
        $('p.quicksearch-false.advancedsearch-true').show();
        $('#advanced').toggle();
        $('#quick').toggle();
        return false;
    });
    $('#quick').click(function () {
        $('p.quicksearch-true.advancedsearch-true').show();
        $('p.quicksearch-true.advancedsearch-false').show();
        $('p.quicksearch-false.advancedsearch-true').hide();
        $('#advanced').toggle();
        $('#quick').toggle();
        return false;
    });
}
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<a href="#" id="quick">quick</a><a href="#" id="advanced">advanced</a>
<p class="quicksearch-true advancedsearch-true">
  Some dynamically generated form field that appears in both quick and advanced search
</p>
<p class="quicksearch-true advancedsearch-false">
  Some dynamically generated form field that appears in quick search only
</p>
<p class="quicksearch-false advancedsearch-true">
  Some dynamically generated form field that appears in advanced search only
</p>
<p class="quicksearch-false advancedsearch-false">
  Should never occur, but if it did, it would remain hidden anyway
</p>
```

So really, I'm after any feedback that you may have that could help me to try to write Better jQuery.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="quick" class="button" data-fields="q-field">Show Quick Form</a> <a href="#" id="advanced" class="button" data-fields="a-field">Show Advanced Form</a>

<p class="field q-field a-field">
  Some dynamically generated form field that appears in both quick and advanced search
</p>
<p class="field q-field">
  Some dynamically generated form field that appears in quick search only
</p>
<p class="field a-field">
  Some dynamically generated form field that appears in advanced search only
</p>
<p class="field">
  Should never occur, but if it did, it would remain hidden anyway
</p>
```

Simplified JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#advanced').show();

    $('.button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.button').toggle('show');
        $('.field').hide().parent().find('p.' + $(this).data('fields')).show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/jsGmD/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way, which can be expanded to as many search modes as you like, simply by adding more to the HTML. The jQuery will work for any number of modes. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/gPZRw/).

#### jQuery:

```
$('.search-modes').children().click(function() {
    $(this).hide().siblings().show(); //Hide this button, show the others

    var mode = $(this).data('mode');  //What mode are we in?

    $('.search').children().each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass(mode))
            $(this).show();           //Show things that are in this mode
        else
            $(this).hide();           //Hide the rest
    });
    return false;
}).first().click();                   //Start in quick mode
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="search-modes">
    <a href="#" data-mode="quick">quick</a>
    <a href="#" data-mode="advanced">advanced</a>
</div>
<div class="search">
    <p class="quick advanced">
        Some dynamically generated form field that appears in both quick and advanced search
    </p>
    <p class="quick">
        Some dynamically generated form field that appears in quick search only
    </p>
    <p class="advanced">
        Some dynamically generated form field that appears in advanced search only
    </p>
    <p>
        Should never occur, but if it did, it would remain hidden anyway
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks much nicer already! Although in this case I don't need it, I do like the extra flexibility.

Comment: The other benefit of this solution over some of the others is that no elements are hidden then immediately shown again, which can cause things to jump.

Comment: -1 for using an unnecessary `each()` iteration with a nested `if`. Your "solution" is ridiculously slower than the original script. See for yourself: http://jsperf.com/optimal-jquery-test

Comment: @Matt Anderson: Why is that unnecessary? Internally, calling `show()` boils down to an `each()`. And if I were to hide everything, then show the rest, that would result in a jumping document, losing the scroll position.

Surely the click event won't be fired in that js test, will it?

Comment: @Matt Anderson:There's a reason mine runs orders of magnitude slower. The click event is triggered by my code, but not his. Therefore, in his code, you're measuring the time taken to bind the event, whereas in mine there's the overhead of running the event once. I'm not really sure, but I think [this shows interesting behaviour](http://jsperf.com/optimal-jquery-test/4).

Comment: Regardless of which solution is the best one, the discussion between you both equally interesting and informative for a beginner. So thank you and +1 to you both :)

Answer (score 1):

In short, your code and markup is far too bloated for what you're trying to do.

I would scale back the markup to more like the following where

a) The shared fields are always onscreen and dont get hidden/shown
b) The case which should never occur is removed - its irrelevant to the problem
c) You don't have true/false versions of the classes - they are boolean; either there or not

```
<a href="#" id="quick">quick</a><a href="#" id="advanced">advanced</a>
<p>
  Some dynamically generated form field that appears in both quick and advanced search
</p>
<p class="quicksearch">
  Some dynamically generated form field that appears in quick search only
</p>
<p class="advancedsearch">
  Some dynamically generated form field that appears in advanced search only
</p>
```

Then your jQuery becoomes much much cleaner

```
$('#quick').toggle();
$('.advancedsearch').hide();

$('#advanced').click(function () {
     $('p.quicksearch').hide();
     $('p.advancedsearch').show();
     $('#advanced').toggle();
     $('#quick').toggle();
});
$('#quick').click(function () {
    $('p.quicksearch').show();
    $('p.advancedsearch').hide();
    $('#advanced').toggle();
    $('#quick').toggle();
});
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6nkXN/

Comment: Thanks Jamiec for your suggestion, unfortunately with your version of the html I can no longer have a field that appears in both the quick AND the advanced search, hence why I need the two classes on each p tag.

Comment: @Tweety - Yes, you can. Read again. I have left your "shared" element in the markup and the live example demonstrates that it is always on the page.

Comment: Oh of course! My bad, yes I see it now, if the item appears in both quick and advanced search, then no need for jQuery to do anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing markup:

```
function searchModes() {
$('.quicksearch-true').show();
$('.quicksearch-false').hide();
$('#advanced').show();
$('#quick').hide();

$('#advanced').click(function () {
    $('.advancedsearch-true').show();
    $('.advancedsearch-false').hide();
    $('#advanced, #quick').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('#quick').click(function () {
    $('.quicksearch-true').show();
    $('.quicksearch-false').hide();        
    $('#advanced, #quick').toggle();
    return false;
});
```